# Need help with Apex Batch job

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex

I need to:

Implement a batch job to Delete records that are past 60 days.

Use helper class to implement the logic for deletion.

Use the wrapper class in helper class to return the DML results to batch job.

Within finish method create a visualforce template to send the log results.

Please help as I am working first time with  Apex Batch Job.

I have managed to write this so far:

```
//Batch Job for Processing the Records
global class ITSDeleteIntegrationJobRecords implements Database.Batchable<sobject>,Database.Stateful{
      global String [] email = new String[] {'myEmail'};

//Start Method
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'select Id, name, createddate FROM Integration_Job__c WHERE createddate < LAST_N_DAYS:60';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Integration_Job__c>scope){
        for(Integration_Job__c intJob:scope){
            if(scope.size()>0)
      delete scope;
      Database.emptyRecycleBin(scope);
        }        
   }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the number of deletes is not massive, the `Database.Stateful` approach is a good one. Store in a property the information from the `execute` method you want to email and email that information in the `finish` method using the [SingleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) classes.

I suggest these changes:

- unless you are creating a managed package, use `public` not `global`
- in the `start` method, use static SOQL not dynamic SOQL (Google to discover the difference)
- in the `execute` method, delete the whole list in one DML statement rather than one at a time
- see the [DeleteResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_deleteresult.htm) class for how to find out what the results are
- add code to the finish method to send the email; Google about Visualforce Email Templates for how to use those
- write a unit test

I would start out doing all this inline (not in a helper class) and see how clean the result is. If your company has a policy to always move code out of triggers, then you can do that as a second step. But in this case, the overall result is likely to be worse if you do that than leaving the code inline.

**PS**

Hang on, isn't "move code out of triggers" a "best practice"? Well yes that is often said, but in reality, that approach is a solution to a set of problems, and if those problems don't exist, or attempting to solve those problems creates worse problems, then it is not always the right thing to do. Be wary of that label - see e.g. [There is no such thing as "Best Practices": Context Matters](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/there-is-no-such-thing-as-best-practices-context-matters/).

Another example of a good idea getting treated as something you should always do is mentioned in Martin Fowler's new edition of his excellent [Refactoring](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) book. On the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) his view is:

> I'd prefer it to be called the Occasionally Useful Suggestion of
>   Demeter.

**PPS**

How to use a helper class. Note the `static` on the helper method.

```
public class ITSDeleteIntegrationJobRecords implements Database.Batchable<sobject>,Database.Stateful {

    private String[] emailAddresses;
    private String[] results = new String[] {};

    public ITSDeleteIntegrationJobRecords(String[] emailAddresses) {
        this.emailAddresses = emailAddresses;
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            select Id, name, createddate
            from Integration_Job__c
            where createddate < LAST_N_DAYS:60
        ]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Integration_Job__c> scope) {
        results.addAll(MyHelper.execute(scope));      
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        String s = 'Results are\n\n' + String.join(results, '\n');
        // Send to emailAddresses using a template
    }
} 

public class MyHelper {
    public static String[] execute(List<Integration_Job__c> scope) {
        // Delete and extract results
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out @Keith C. I have to write the delete logic in the helper class, I have written the helper class but getting error when referring it to my Batch class or may be I referenced it incorrectly.Any example on how to refer the helper class in the Batch class 'Execute' method?.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @SumonGanguly See the PPS.

Comment: +1 for `Law of Demeter`